# Exhaust system pipe welding

Tags: welding, exhaust

[image]

Hi everyone I have an exhaust for a motorcycle which I have to modify.
The trouble is pipe which connects to the end can is of a different diameter to the bit it's supposed to connect to on the downpipes...
how do I weld two piped of varying diameter together please so that it kind of tapers from the bigger to smaller and connects symmetrically?
like the pic... the two rectangles represent the pipes and the bit in middle the taper between them

Comment: Draw out the shape on paper so when it is curved it matches the two diameters, then use that as a template to cut your steel.

Comment: so you're suggesting I cut a tapered middle bit like in the middle? but how would I do that?

Comment: Have a look here : http://craig-russell.co.uk/demos/cone_calculator/

Comment: Or cut slots in the larger pipe and bend them down but it won't be pretty, failing that find a metalworker to do the job...

Comment: lol i can do the math look at my username :) my issue is actually doing it- what do I use to physically taper it so precisely?

Comment: Once you have cut the correct shape out then you need to bend it - and if you bend it properly the cut edges will meet.

Comment: Or go to an exhaust shop and see what they have

Comment: Some people will shy away from helping you if you state you are trying to "cut out the cat" just because that can be illegal in some areas.  Maybe it's fine for you to do it, but you might get more help if you leave out that detail.

Comment: @JPhi1618 cheers :) edited.

Comment: @SolarMike cheers

Comment: first look and see if there are commercial adapters available to weld or even clamp in place.

Comment: Really? Sheet metal workers spend an entire apprenticeship to learn to do what you are asking. Layout, scribe, cut, bend, tack, and weld. It takes specific (expensive) equipment and skill to do this "precisely", as you say.